# PHP Syntax error unexpected ending while using if-else in input tag

Tags: php, html

I'm getting syntax error when i use if-else inside form <input tag using php to change Value

```
        <input type="text" name="ecsname" class="form-control"
            <?php if(empty($_GET['id'])){?>
                value="" <?php}else{?> 
                value="<?php echo $res->cshort;?>"
            <?php}?>
       >
```

Comment: before input, use condition and store value in 1 variable. in input, directly assign that variable

Comment: what error you getting? Code looking fine. Have you checked whether `$_GET['id']` available or not?

Comment: getting unexpected ending error

Comment: Add a space between `<?php` and your opening/closing braces.

Answer (score 1):

You can clean up your existing code so it's much nicer to read and also separates out the logic from the output.

```
<?php $ecsname_value = empty($_GET['id'])?"":$res->cshort;?>
<input type="text" name="ecsname" class="form-control" value="<?=$ecsname_value;?>">
```

`<?php $ecsname_value = empty($_GET['id'])?"":$res->cshort;?>` is a shorter version of your if/else using the ternary operator.

This assumes that $res->cshort is defined somewhere.